# Table position absolute not working in IE9 and IE10

Tags: html, css

I have a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/0b3qcg0g/2/ (table positioned on right side of its container).

This works on every browser except IE9-IE10. Problem is simple: on IE9 and IE10 I table wont position itself correctly.

Here are solutions I cannot use:

- I cannot give `display: block;` for table because I need table
  layout.
- For same reason, cannot change table element to div element
- Cannot set table width by pixels because I need width in percentages.

Can anyone please help me?

Edit:

Hours of hitting my head on a wall and just when I ask for help I figure out the solution. For somebody else who has this same problem: jsfiddle.net/0b3qcg0g/3

Comment: Rather than editing your question, you could post an answer to this question and mark it as such. That way, this answer will show up as an answered question, rather than an unanswered one. Thank you.

Comment: @VictorZamanian Sure

Answer (score 1):

try add to #table left:50% instead right 0, it works for me:)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This could work, but I just figured out a solution myself.

Comment: let me know when you got it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `table-layout: fixed` to the table styles? That seems to work for me in IE10:

http://codepen.io/a_double/pen/JoXJmV

Comment: Actually I just got it working. :D http://jsfiddle.net/0b3qcg0g/3/. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Weird... it's working fine for me in IE8 and up. Either way, I'm glad to hear you found a solution!